# Craft CMS hangs when deleting a field then throws 504

Tags: craft3, admin, sql

We have an instance of Craft CMS running that has a lot of content entries and a lot of fields, using Neo and SuperTable. At some point, something changed and now when we try to delete one of the fields the CMS will just hang until it eventually throws a 504 error and sometimes seeing an error like `sql timeout exceeded error`. Any idea how to track this down?

Some additional info, I keep seeing this error in the logs `yii\web\NotFoundHttpException: axios.min.map does not exist.`

Also getting a failed POST request for /index.php?p=admin/actions/fields/delete-field

-- NEO 2.7.25

-- Asset Rev 6.0.2

-- DigitalOcean Spaces Volume 1.1.2

-- Redactor 2.6.1

-- Sprout Forms 3.12.2

-- Super table 2.5.4

-- Craft Ajaxinate 2.0.1

-- Field Manager 2.1.8

Comment: You mention Digital Ocean, what size droplet?

Comment: 50GB, I have other Craft instances on the server and not having this issue.

Comment: Updated my question with some more details.

Comment: What happens if you restart the mysql server?

Comment: Craft support came through and determined about 30k MySQL queries were being run when we were removing the field due to all of its connections.